# Reducing space of linebreak \\ in a table

Tags: tables, line-spacing

How can I reduce the space between the lines created by `\\` inside the following table?

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.7\textwidth,totalheight=0.97\textheight}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} p{\linewidth}}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textbf{\footnotesize Monetary Policy} \\
\scriptsize 1) Monetary Authority  Loans Through the Asset Backed Commercial Paper Money Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility  AMLF  and Money Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility  MMLF   Asset  Level Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 2) Rest of the World  Other U S  Reserve Assets  Other Claims  Liability  Transactions Lag 0 \\ \scriptsize 3) Monetary Authority  Depository Institution Loans N E C  to Other Financial Business  Commercial Paper Funding Facility LLC   Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 4) Rest of the World  Other U S  Reserve Assets  Other Claims  Liability  Revaluation Lag 0 \\
\textbf{\footnotesize Public Sector} \\
\scriptsize 1) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 0 \\ \scriptsize 2) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Equity Capital of Farm Credit System  Transactions Lag 3 \\ \scriptsize 3) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Equity Capital of Farm Credit System  Transactions Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 4) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 5) Government Sponsored Enterprises  Corporate Equities Held by Freddie Mac  Asset  Level Lag 0 \\ \scriptsize 6) Rest of the World  U S  Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF  Liability  Revaluation Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 7) General Government  Other Accounts Payable Including SDR Allocations  Liability  IMA   Revaluation Lag 4 \\\scriptsize  8) State and Local Governments  Foreign Bonds  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
\textbf{\footnotesize Labor Market} \\
\scriptsize 1) Employment Level   Agriculture and Related Industries  Wage and Salary Workers Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 2) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds  Total Time and Savings Deposits  Asset  Transactions Lag 0 \\ \scriptsize 3) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds  Total Time and Savings Deposits  Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 4) Unemployment Rate   Nonagriculture  Private Wage and Salary Workers Lag 3 \\ \scriptsize 5) Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the Rest of the World  Asset  FWTW   Revaluation Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 6) Pension Funds  Corporate Equities  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ \scriptsize 7) Domestic Financial Sectors  Insurance  Pension and Standardized Guarantee Schemes  Asset  IMA   Revaluation Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 8) Private Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements  Asset  Transactions Lag 3 \\ \scriptsize  9) Private Pension Funds  Security Repurchase Agreements  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ 
\textbf{\footnotesize Recession} \\
\scriptsize 1) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Period following the Peak through the Trough Lag 2 \\ \scriptsize 2) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the Period preceding the Trough Lag 3 \\ \scriptsize 3) OECD based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the Trough Lag 2 \\ \scriptsize 4) OECD based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak through the Trough 1 Lag 2 \\ 
\textbf{\footnotesize Housing and Mortgages} \\
\scriptsize 1) Households and Nonprofit Organizations  Commercial and Multifamily Residential Mortgages  Asset  Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 2) Households and Nonprofit Organizations  Commercial and Multifamily Residential Mortgages  Asset  Transactions Lag 2 \\ \scriptsize 3) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by RTC  Asset  Level Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 4) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages  Asset  Transactions Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 5) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by Public Housing Administration  PHA   Asset  Transactions Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 6) Federal Government  One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by RTC  Asset  Level Lag 3 \\ 
\textbf{\footnotesize Private Sector} \\
\scriptsize 1) Rest of the World  Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean Financial Subsidiaries of U S  Corporations  Asset  Revaluation Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 2)  Security Brokers and Dealers  Payables to Customer and Rest of the World Noncustomers  Free Credit  Margin Deposits  and Other Payables   Liability  Transactions Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 3) Total Consumer Credit Owned by Depository Institutions  Flow Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 4) Domestic Financial Sectors  Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings Retained Abroad and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid  Other Than for Financial Stabilization Program   Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 5) Rest of the World  Debt Securities and Negotiable Certificates of Deposit Issued by Financial Corporations  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 6) Holding Companies  Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the Rest of the World  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 0 \\ \scriptsize 7) Private Depository Institutions  Total Time and Savings Deposits  Liability  Transactions Lag 1 \\ \scriptsize 8) Rest of the World  Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean Financial Subsidiaries of U S  Corporations  Asset  Transactions Lag 0 \\  \scriptsize 9)  Nonprofit Organizations  Municipal Securities  Sum of Holders   Liability  FWTW   Transactions Lag 4 \\ \scriptsize 10) Domestic Financial Sectors  Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings Retained Abroad and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid  Other Than for Financial Stabilization Program   Transactions Lag 2 \\ \scriptsize 11) Other Financial Corporations and Insurance Companies and Pension Funds  Net Claims on Nonfinancial Businesses and Households and Nonprofit Organizations  Asset  FWTW   Transactions Lag 4 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{ } 
\end{table}
```

Comment: don't scale tables, especialy don't scale both height and width or you will distort the text so I would start by removing `\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.7\textwidth,totalheight=0.97\textheight}`  hard to comment further without a real example as you have given no indication of font or page sizes. There should also be no `\\ ` after `\hline` so remove the `\\[-1.8ex]`

Comment: You obvously know about `\\[...]` for specific lines.  There is also ``\arraystretch`` (macro scale factor) for the built in strut, but it won't make things smaller than the font height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `tabular` to begin with and you don't want to scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]

\fontsize{6}{7}\selectfont
\newcommand{\theader}[1]{\par\smallskip{\scriptsize\bfseries#1\par}}

\hrule height 1pt
\prevdepth=0pt

\theader{Monetary Policy}

1) Monetary Authority Loans Through the Asset Backed Commercial
   Paper Money Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility AMLF and
   Money Market Mutual Fund Liquidity Facility MMLF Asset Level Lag~1

2) Rest of the World Other US Reserve Assets Other Claims Liability
   Transactions Lag~0

3) Monetary Authority Depository Institution Loans NEC to Other Financial
   Business Commercial Paper Funding Facility LLC Asset Transactions Lag~1

4) Rest of the World Other US Reserve Assets Other Claims Liability
   Revaluation Lag~0

\theader{Public Sector}

1) Rest of the World US Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions
   and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF
   Liability Revaluation Lag~0

2) Government Sponsored Enterprises Equity Capital of Farm Credit System
   Transactions Lag~3

3) Government Sponsored Enterprises Equity Capital of Farm Credit System
   Transactions Lag~4

4) Rest of the World US Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions
   and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF
   Liability Revaluation Lag~1

5) Government Sponsored Enterprises Corporate Equities Held by Freddie
   Mac Asset Level Lag~0

6) Rest of the World US Government Loans Excluding Capital Subscriptions
   and Contributions to International Financial Institutions and the IMF
   Liability Revaluation Lag~4

7) General Government Other Accounts Payable Including SDR Allocations
   Liability IMA Revaluation Lag~4

8) State and Local Governments Foreign Bonds Asset FWTW Transactions Lag~2

\theader{Labor Market}

1) Employment Level Agriculture and Related Industries Wage and Salary
   Workers Lag~1

2) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds
   Total Time and Savings Deposits Asset Transactions Lag~0

3) State and Local Government Employee Defined Benefit Retirement Funds
   Total Time and Savings Deposits Asset Transactions Lag~1

4) Unemployment Rate Nonagriculture Private Wage and Salary Workers
   Lag~3

5) Pension Funds Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the Rest of the
   World Asset FWTW Revaluation Lag~4

6) Pension Funds Corporate Equities Asset Transactions Lag~2

7) Domestic Financial Sectors Insurance Pension and Standardized Guarantee
   Schemes Asset IMA Revaluation Lag~4

8) Private Pension Funds Security Repurchase Agreements Asset Transactions
   Lag~3

9) Private Pension Funds Security Repurchase Agreements Asset Transactions
   Lag~2

\theader{Recession}

1) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Period
   following the Peak through the Trough Lag~2

2) NBER based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak
   through the Period preceding the Trough Lag~3

3) OECD based Recession Indicators for the United States from the Peak
   through the Trough Lag~2 \\ 4) OECD based Recession Indicators for
   the United States from the Peak through the Trough 1 Lag~2

\theader{Housing and Mortgages}

1) Households and Nonprofit Organizations Commercial and Multifamily
   Residential Mortgages Asset Transactions Lag~1

2) Households and Nonprofit Organizations Commercial and Multifamily
   Residential Mortgages Asset Transactions Lag~2

3) Federal Government One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by
   RTC Asset Level Lag~1

4) Federal Government One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Asset
   Transactions Lag~4

5) Federal Government One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by
   Public Housing Administration PHA Asset Transactions Lag~4

6) Federal Government One to Four Family Residential Mortgages Held by
   RTC Asset Level Lag~3

\theader{Private Sector}

1) Rest of the World Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean
   Financial Subsidiaries of US Corporations Asset Revaluation Lag~4

2) Security Brokers and Dealers Payables to Customer and Rest of the
   World Noncustomers Free Credit Margin Deposits and Other Payables
   Liability Transactions Lag~4

3) Total Consumer Credit Owned by Depository Institutions Flow Lag~1

4) Domestic Financial Sectors Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings
   Retained Abroad and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid Other
   Than for Financial Stabilization Program Transactions Lag~1

5) Rest of the World Debt Securities and Negotiable Certificates of
   Deposit Issued by Financial Corporations Asset FWTW Transactions
   Lag~1

6) Holding Companies Security Repurchase Agreements Issued by the
   Rest of the World Asset FWTW Transactions Lag~0

7) Private Depository Institutions Total Time and Savings Deposits
   Liability Transactions Lag~1

8) Rest of the World Corporate Bonds Issued by Netherlands Antillean
   Financial Subsidiaries of US Corporations Asset Transactions Lag~0

9) Nonprofit Organizations Municipal Securities Sum of Holders
   Liability FWTW Transactions Lag~4

10) Domestic Financial Sectors Net Saving Including Foreign Earnings
    Retained Abroad and CCAdj Less Net Capital Transfers Paid Other
    Than for Financial Stabilization Program Transactions Lag~2

11) Other Financial Corporations and Insurance Companies and Pension
    Funds Net Claims on Nonfinancial Businesses and Households and
    Nonprofit Organizations Asset FWTW Transactions Lag~4

\smallskip
\hrule height 1pt


\caption{ } 

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

You might be able to use a larger font size depending on the page size of your document.

The `showframe` package is only used for showing that the table fits with the standard page parameters.

[image]

Of course this is unreadable and you should rethink on how you want to present the data.

Comment: Thank you. That is really helpful! Worked.